# font Issue in WPF on Some Client PCs

Tags: wpf, fonts

I have created an application in WPF & used Arial & Verdana fonts
in TextBlocks & TextBoxes using the Font fallBack Syntax

it is working fine but on some client PCs i m getting an Issue of Font getting corrupt (both Arial & verdana)
I dont actually know that the fonts are corrupt or not i tried reinstalling the fonts
sometimes it works but sometimes it does not work

i m not able to get that this issue is with the Application or it is something related to the System..........

if i m able to get a permanent solution in my application it would be great.........
else i need some solution so that on those system i will be able to run my application properly......

i badly need some solution.............

Thanx in Advance

Comment: Can you post a screenshot so we can see what you mean by "corrupt"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF uses a special cache for fonts.  It can get corrupted on some machines with crappy video cards/drivers.  [This article describes how to fix this issue.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937135)  I've had this issue on my dev box and it worked.